# Mystery link containing fragment identifier in malicious email

Tags: email, phishing, uri

The following link was received in a suspected phishing attack email. Unfortunately, the recipient clicked on the link in their outlook client:

```
<tr>
    <td class="m_-[string-of-19-numbers]m_-[string-of-19-numbers]gmail-x_gmail-summaryIfMobile" style="text-decoration:none;padding:18.1px 13px;background-color:rgb(212,238,246);font-family:Trebuchet MS;font-size:11px;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-align:left;color:rgb(80,80,80)">
    This summary of your queued emails for the last 7 days. Please use the
    retrieve queued emails to release emails your email account <a 
    rel="noopener noreferrer" href="http://#%23email%23%23" target="_blank">info@email.address</a> inbox.</td>
</tr>
```

The user reported that it opened a new window in their web browser (firefox), which is expected based on the `target`. I'm trying to determine the possible scope of the breach. Ordinarily I would assume `http://#%23email%23%23` is a broken link, since there's no actual resource identifier before the fragment identifier. However, given the phishing and the client-side nature of fragment identifier interpretation, I'm left wondering:

What was the attacker trying to do with this link? How can fragment identifiers be abused? Are there other areas of this email that I should look to for clues?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have an idea. It boils down to "they goofed". Let me lay out my reasoning first, though:

1. `%23` is percent-encoding. It's how you encode special characters in a URL. The format is a percent sign, followed by the hex value of the byte being encoded. You'll also see it frequently with parens (`%28`/`%29`), spaces (`%20`), and equals signs (`%3D`).
2. So `%23` = whatever codepoint 0x23 is, aka `#`.
3. So their URL is equivalent to `##email##`, once URL decoded.
4. `##email##` isn't very likely to appear in random text, so it'd make a good template string.
5. A *lot* of things -- email clients, browsers, Markdown parsers, whatever -- will try to automatically correct broken URLs. For example, adding `https://` in front, and *url-encoding characters to avoid ambiguity*.

So based on that reasoning, here's what I think happened:

1. They had some mass-market phishing email template, ready to be blasted out to millions of potential suckers.
2. As part of that, they had a placeholder for the phishing URL, to be replaced when the email is sent out.
3. Either:

   - They use something like Markdown, which is rendered to HTML, and *then* do their template replacement. The rendering engine they use autocorrects URLs, so `##email##` got changed, and therefore didn't get replaced by a naive search-and-replace.
   - They just plumb forgot to do the replacement, and something between them sending and you receiving (maybe even your email server) replaced the extra `#`s with `%23`. If you're looking at the source in the Inspect pane of a browser, it's likely that your browser is 'correcting' the URL, to show where it's been interpreted as pointing to.

In short: They're probably not trying some complex exploit. They did their spam wrong. Barring something *extremely* weird in your browser, you should be fine.

Still definitely get that employee retrained, though. This time, they got lucky. Next time, they might not.

Comment: This rings true to me, I didn't consider that the initial link may have been "corrected" at some point and rewritten. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @schroeder The snippet contains `#%23email%23%23` (with one "real" `#` and three encoded ones) so would render to `##email##`.

Comment: @TripeHound darn it, I missed that! I still think that with the rendering issue, they pulled a "Dwigt".